# how to set the average age on the empty cells in awk

Tags: awk

The dataset I am working with is the following:

```
$ cat file
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
```

I wrote an `awk` script to replace the empty cells from column Age to the average value from the rest of the people.

The code is as follows:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     NR==FNR &&
     $7{sum+=$7;
     elementos++;
     next}
     !$7{$7=media}
     {print}
     ENDFILE{media=sum/elementos}
```

The given result is the following:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
```

As you can see, the code only shows those rows where the age was added but don't show all the values.
Apart from that, the first row with the titles is also removed.

The expected value, i.e, would be:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,44.5,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
```

Notice that average age for the sample is *44.5* and so is shown in the row: `6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,*44.5*,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q`

What is wrong in here?
I need to do it with a loop and using `awk`.

---

Original question:

The dataset I am working with is the following:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
```

I wrote an `awk` script to replace the empty cells from column Age to the average value from the rest of the people.

The code is as follows:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     NR==FNR && 
     $7{sum+=$7; 
     elementos++; 
     next}
     !$7{$7=media}
     {print > "/tmp/train4.csv" }
     ENDFILE{media=sum/elementos}
```

The given result is the following:

```
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
18,1,2,"Williams, Mr. Charles Eugene",male,,0,0,244373,13,,S
20,1,3,"Masselmani, Mrs. Fatima",female,,0,0,2649,7.225,,C
27,0,3,"Emir, Mr. Farred Chehab",male,,0,0,2631,7.225,,C
29,1,3,"O'Dwyer, Miss. Ellen ""Nellie""",female,,0,0,330959,7.8792,,Q
30,0,3,"Todoroff, Mr. Lalio",male,,0,0,349216,7.8958,,S
32,1,1,"Spencer, Mrs. William Augustus (Marie Eugenie)",female,,1,0,PC 17569,146.5208,B78,C
33,1,3,"Glynn, Miss. Mary Agatha",female,,0,0,335677,7.75,,Q
37,1,3,"Mamee, Mr. Hanna",male,,0,0,2677,7.2292,,C
43,0,3,"Kraeff, Mr. Theodor",male,,0,0,349253,7.8958,,C
46,0,3,"Rogers, Mr. William John",male,,0,0,S.C./A.4. 23567,8.05,,S
```

As you can see, the code only shows those rows where the age was added but don't show all the values.
Apart from that, the first row with the titles is also removed.

The expected value, i.e, would be:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,31.2,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
...
```

Notice that average age for the 6-row sample is *31.2* and so is shown in the 6th row: `6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,*31.2*,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q`

What is wrong in here?
I need to do it with a loop and using `awk`.

Comment: `media` is undefined until *after* the file has been processed, so *while* processing the input lines this means `$7=media` is the same as `$7=""`, hence the lines of output with nothing in field #7; as for why all the other lines are missing from the output ... `FNR==NR && $7` equates to true because field #7 is non-empty and since the last action you take is `next` you skip the rest of the `awk` script (including the `print`) so these lines don't show up in the output

Comment: As mentioned in my comments on your previous question - for any question to be a good question for this forum, and so likely to get answers instead of downvotes and close votes, you've **GOT** to show the expected output for the sample input you posted. Showing output you get that you don't want can be useful additionally, but we can't tell what you do want from code that doesn't do what you want plus output that isn't what you want. We need both sample input and the expected output given that input to be able to copy/paste it to test a potential solution against.

Comment: since `media` is not known until *after* the entire file has been processed you have a couple options ... load the entire file into memory (eg, via `awk` arrays) and during `END{FILE}` processing update the array entries with `media` and then print the entire array ... or ... process the input file twice, obtaining the `media` after the first pass and then updating field #7 during the 2nd pass; all of this assumes the `Name` field always contains a *single* embedded comma else the hardcoded `$7` is going to point to the 'wrong' field

Comment: You say `I wrote an awk script to replace the empty cells from age` but `age` is your 6th field, not 7th (I assume you're trying to accomodate the potential `,` in   the `Name`` field but that's the wrong approach), and you say ` need to do it with a loop...` - why do you think you need a loop and what would you want to loop over?

Comment: I see you added partial expected output with a `...` line at the end - no, we can't test with that by doing a simple diff on actual output vs expected. Show the **exact** expected output for the sample input you provided. If it's not worth providing more output because some of your input isn't useful to provide the output for, then reduce the input to the useful set, don't stop part-way through the output.

Comment: @EdMorton, I added the expected value. It was also there what I got by executing the code. I can't show what I am trying to do because I can't. If so, I wouldn't ask the question here. I am trying to calculate the average value of the non-empty rows and this value should be assign to the Age cells that are empty. Unfortunately I can't give more information.

Comment: No-one is asking for more information, just simplicity, clarity, and consistency in the information you do provide. In addition to the expected output issue I mentioned, it's impossible to get the output you say you get from the input you provided. Please make this clear and simple for us by providing sample input, the exact, complete, output you want given that sample input and, optionally, the output you currently get but don't want from that sample input, not partial output and/or output you'd get from some other input than what you've shown us.

Comment: @markp-fuso, and how would then you do it?

Comment: I've already provided a couple ideas for how to process the file and add the `media`; as for the hardcoded $7 a google search on `awk parse csv with embedded commas` will bring up quite a few hits (I'd focus on the answers that reference `FPAT`)

Comment: @EdMorton, I can't give the exact output sorry. The dataset contains about 800 rows and the code can run exactly for the shown amount of rows I guess. Sorry if I am not being capable of asking my question clear enough. I am just showing my dataset (part of it), the code i wrote, the result I get, explain what is going wrong with it and how should it looks like.

Comment: @markp-fuso, ok, I understand what you mean but unfortunately I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I'm trying to teach you how to ask a good question so you can get good answers to this and any other questions you ask in future. So far you haven't been asking good questions which is why you're getting very few answers (including some bad ones) and it's not significantly more effort for you to write a good question as it is a bad one - all you need is a [mcve] with code, sample input, and the expected output from that input and it'll be easy for us to help you once you've provided that. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: I'm not asking you to provide 800 rows of output, just the output for the 10 or so rows of input you have provided. If the 10 rows of input you provided so far aren't adequate to demonstrate the problem you need help with then update them so they do. That's the meaning of creating a [mcve] - you create a minimal example that demonstrates your problem so we can best help you.

Comment: I just updated the question for you so you can see how to provide a [mcve] for your future questions.

Comment: Notice that the sample input in your question is now **minimal** (i.e. the fewest rows that can demonstrate the problem), the unwanted actual output IS the output your tool produces given that input, and the expected output is the complete output you'd expect given that input - THAT along with your code is a [mcve] as required for a question on this forum. See [ask] if that's not clear. I also changed `print > "/tmp/train4.csv"` to just `print` in your code as printing to another file is just a complicating distraction and nothing to do with the problem you're asking for help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk for `FPAT` (which you must already be using for `ENDFILE`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")"
    OFS = ","
    ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[1]
}
NR == FNR {
    if ( FNR>1 && $6 ) {
        sum += $6
        elementos++
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    media = ( elementos ? sum / elementos : 0 )
}
!$6 {
    $6 = media
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,44.5,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
```

I'm assuming you want `elementos` to be a count of the data rows that had `age` populate, not the total count of data rows, and that an age of 0 should be treated the same way as a missing age.

The ternary expression `elementos ? sum / elementos : 0` is required so you don't get a divide by zero error if no non-zero `age`s are present in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions/Understandings (from OP's comments):

- all `Name` data contains a single embedded comma, so with a comma defined as the field delimiter the `Age` column is actually field #7
- output format for the average `Age` includes a single digit to the right of the decimal
- input file size is unknown at this point so to keep from running into potential memory issues we'll look at an `awk` solution that makes 2 passes over the input file

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="," }                              # input/output field delimiter is comma

# FNR==NR ==> process 1st input file

FNR==NR { if (FNR > 1)                              # ignore header row
             if ($7+0 == $7) {                      # if field #7 is non-empty and a number then ...
                elementos++                         # keep track of number of non-empty fields
                sum+=$7                             # add to our running sum
             }
          next
        }

# the rest of this script is for processing the 2nd input file

FNR==1  { media = 0                                 # while processing the header go ahead and determine the average
          if (elementos>0) 
             media = sprintf("%.1f", sum/elementos)
          print                                     # print the header row
          next                                      # skip to the next line of input
        }
        { if ($7=="")                               # if field #7 is empty ...
             $7 = media                             # set field #7 to the average
          print                                     # print the current line
        }
' input.csv input.csv > output.csv
```

Using *only* the OP's sample 8-line input file this generates:

```
$ cat output.csv
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,35.0,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S

$ diff input.csv output.csv
7c8
< 6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
---
> 6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,35.0,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
```

From the `diff` output we see `PassengerID=6` has the blank `Age` column updated with the average of `35.0`.

---

Assuming the `Name` column may not always contain a single embedded comma, the OP will want to look at a solution that can handle such a case.  One idea would be to look at the `GNU awk / FPAT` feature.

Answer (score 0):

I like ruby for quick CSV things:

```sh
ruby -rcsv -e '
    data = CSV.read(ARGV.shift)
    col = data[0].index("Age")
    ages = data
            .drop(1)
            .map {|row| row[col]}
            .reject(&:nil?)
            .map(&:to_i)
    media = ages.sum / ages.size
    data.each {|row| 
        row[col] ||= media
        puts CSV.generate_line(row)
    }
' file
```